# NPDA for L= {w ∈ {a,b}*: number of a's is twice the number of b's}

Tags: computation-theory

I have been trying to find a NPDA for this language but I can't come up with anything that will accept all of the words in the language. I did try making its accepting condition an empty stack and using the stack alphabet {$ a b} but maybe I should try something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking the equivalent `Grammar` for the given `Regular Expression`.
If so maybe this one with the following productions:

```
S->AAb | SAAb | ASAb | AASb | AAbS
A->a
```

Some Tests:

```
aab : S->AAb->aAb->aab
aaaabb : S-> AASb -> AA(AAb)b -> aaaabb
```

Could check also with other example and see if fit on all cases.

If fine always should have on
 `Result = (2*count_of_b) for a, count_b`

Looking twice, `A->a` can be removed and have only:

```
S->aab|Saab|aSab|aaSb|aabS
```

Test:

```
aaaabb : aaSb(S_4)->aaaabb(S_1), etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

The context free grammer for number of a's is twice the number of b's is:

```
S--> aaSb / €(epsilon)
```

Push down automata can be done for a^2nb^n.push down automata is nothing but the **finite automata with memory (can be stack).**

- Here, for every two a's push one 'a' into the stack and for the input symbol 'b' pop 'a' from the stack.
- At the end, if the stack is empty then the string is accepted.

PDA image for a^2nb^n:

[image: PDA image for a^2nb^n]

```
δ(q0,a,z0)=(q0,az0)
δ(q0,a,a)=(q1,a)
δ(q1,a,a)=(q0,aa)
δ(q1,b,a)=(q2,ϵ)
δ(q2,b,a)=(q2,ϵ)
δ(q2,ϵ,z0)=(q3,z0)
```

where,

- Q={q0,q1,q2,q3}
- Σ=(a,b)
- q0=initial state
- q3=final state

From the figure for the odd number of a's push into the stack and for even a's skip.Then for each 'b' pop one 'a' from the stack. At the end, an empty stack represents that the string is accepted.

Comment: The question is n(a) = 2n(b), which means ordering can be anything... your answer does not include abbaaa.